# how to get right datetime format?

Tags: javascript, datetime, kendo-ui

There is a need to convert a datetime to right format, currently I get 
"2015-06-15T15:01:12 +2:00", and I need
"2015-06-15T15:01:12 + 02:00". 
I don't know how to get a zero in front of the hour. I cannot save a record if I don't get this format. I tried to modify it in firefox network and with zero works great, tried to modify code to get zero behind 2 and couldn't, it always goes somewhere else.

```
 '","StartTime": "' + ((!data.StartTime) ? 0 : kendo.toString(data.StartTime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ss z:00")) + '"}';
```

I appreciate Your help.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
 '","StartTime": "' + ((!data.StartTime) ? 0 : kendo.toString(data.StartTime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ss+02:00")) + '"}';
```